# Is there a difference between 杀害 and 杀死?

Tags: vocabulary

I have tried browsing examples, but the only potential difference I see is that you can say "它也会杀死庄稼", but I am not sure if 杀害 also refers to plants.

Answer (score 6):

害 in **杀害** (kill; **murder**) means 'victimize'. You can only victimize creatures that have emotion, capable of feeling pain. '杀害' mostly refer to murder of human; And only killing of human can be deemed 'murder'

*Note: only human intentionally killing other human is called 'murder' . A tiger killing a human is not a murder, but a killing*

**杀死** (**kill** someone/ something **dead**) can apply to any living organism, from single cell bacteria to human

Answer (score 5):

For most case, the **杀害** emphasizes on the **purpose**(the intention of killing), and the **杀死** emphasizes on the **result**:

- In **杀害**, the `杀` and `害` are both verb, and both meaning **to kill**, they almost have same meaning, just the `害` is more like **make it suffer**, so **杀害** shouldn't refers to plants, unless it's personified to suffer.
- And in **杀死**, it means **kill something dead**, the `杀` is the **kill** part and `死` is the **dead** part, so it can refers to anything that is alive and **can die**, like plants in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation, and welcome to the community :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just share some of my own understandings here.

杀死 and 杀害 are all verbs. 杀死了 and 杀害了 show results.

杀死 is just a statement of fact, but 杀害 is accompanied by human's emotions.(Most are pity and compassion emotions)

For example, a good leader is murdered by terrorists or a loyal minister is assassinated by  traitor. If you use 杀害, more expressive of your regret for the dead. If you use 杀死,just statements a fact without human emotions.

Answer (score 0):

杀害 implies killer has bad intention while 杀死 just means to kill